# How to display data base table by using forms.py in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

My name is R Kartheek. I'm new to Django. I know how to display database table by using HTML in Django. But, I don't know by using **forms.py**. Present learning that.

Anyone, please help me with how to print the database table by using **forms.py** in Django. Just like `Modalname.objects.all()` how to use this by using **Forms.py** in Django?

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Emp_Data(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mobile = models.BigIntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    salary = models.IntegerField()
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Emp_Data
from .forms import Emp_Data_Form
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib import messages
# Create your views here.

def Emp_View(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Emp_Data_Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
            last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
            mobile = request.POST.get('mobile')
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            company = request.POST.get('company')
            location = request.POST.get('location')
            salary = request.POST.get('salary')

            data = Emp_Data(first_name = first_name, last_name = last_name, mobile = mobile, email = email, company = company, salary = salary )
            data.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Data submitted successfully...')
            form = Emp_Data_Form()
            context = {'form':form}
            return render(request, 'empformapp/empdata.html', context)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid form')
    else:
        form = Emp_Data_Form()
        context = {'form':form}
        return render(request, 'empformapp/empdata.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class Emp_Data_Form(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField( label = 'Enter your first name:', widget = forms.TextInput(
                attrs = {
                            'class':'form-control',
                            'placeholder':'First name'
                        }
            )
        )
    last_name = forms.CharField( label = 'Enter your last name:', widget = forms.TextInput(
                attrs = {
                            'class':'form-control',
                            'placeholder':'Last name'
                        }
            )
        )
    mobile = forms.IntegerField( label = 'Enter your mobile number:', widget = forms.NumberInput(
                attrs = {
                            'class':'form-control',
                            'placeholder':'Mobile number'
                        }
            )
        )
    email = forms.EmailField( label = 'Enter your email id:', widget = forms.EmailInput(
                attrs = {
                            'class':'form-control',
                            'placeholder':'Email id'
                        }
            )
        )
    company = forms.CharField( label = 'Enter your Company name:', widget = forms.TextInput(
                attrs = {
                            'class':'form-control',
                            'placeholder':'Company name'
                        }
            )
        )
    location = forms.CharField( label = 'Enter your location:', widget = forms.TextInput(
                attrs = {
                            'class':'form-control',
                            'placeholder':'Your location'
                        }
            )
        )
    salary = forms.IntegerField( label = 'Enter your salary:', widget = forms.NumberInput(
                attrs = {
                            'class':'form-control',
                            'placeholder':'Your salary'
                        }
            )
        )
```

**empdata.html**

```
{% extends "empformapp/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<br>
<!-- Alert message code -->
{% if messages %}
    {% for each_item in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-success{{each_item.tags}}" role="alert">
            {{each_item}}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

    <div class="container text-white">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: indigo;">
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                    <input type="reset" value="Clear" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            {% if form %}
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>First name</th>
                            <th>Last name</th>
                            <th>Mobile</th>
                            <th>Email id</th>
                            <th>Company name</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th>Salary</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for each_item in  form %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{each_item.first_name}}</td>
                                <td>{{each_item.last_name}}</td>
                                <td>{{each_item.mobile}}</td>
                                <td>{{each_item.email}}</td>
                                <td>{{each_item.company}}</td>
                                <td>{{each_item.location}}</td>
                                <td>{{each_item.salary}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            {% else %}
                <h4>Oh no... Data is not available.</h4>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: In your view, your have doubled the work either: It is sufficient to instanciate the form class with the data from `request.POST` as you did and then just call `form.save()`. No need to handle each value in your `form.is_valid()` unless you have to manipulate data before saving.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing redundant work as you define it all twice.
Read the chapter "[Creating forms from models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/)" from the doc.

All you need is this:

```
from django import forms
from .models import *

class Emp_DataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Emp_Data
        fields = '__all__'
```

And you'll be able to render the entire form (except the buttons and the form-tag) with a single template entry (as you did in your example):

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

By the way: You should not use underscores in class-names as they are distinguished from variables (written with underscores). Use EmpData EmpDataForm (CamelCase) instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But, I rectify the issue in my own way. I add this 9th line in  views.py --- all_data = Emp_Data.objects.all() and added this all_data variable in 25th line context = {'form':form, 'all_data':all_data}.  In empdata.html i removed if and add for loop like this {% for each_item in  all_data %} that's it. Problem solved. Thank you.